# Dialogflow - display message with request to /query

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have created an intent with an event. I'm sending a POST request as described in the docs with the proper sessionId (that corresponds to my conversation with my Bot On Slack)
When I send the request, the intent is triggered and the response to my request is correct, but there is no message displayed on Slack. I have double-checked the session, it is correct as I have put a context with some values that I can get back in my request's reponse.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to send requests to dialogflow to display a message for the user. Your service (slack in this case) can send a query to dialogflow from a user input and then print the response, not the other way around.

What you could do instead is to add another endpoint to slack where your fulfillment can send messages directly to slack. In that case the fulfillment could send a query to dialogflow to get a formatted response and then send the response to slack.